# Using $document.off in link function of custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I am using AngularJS 1.3.8.

Within the `link`-function of a custom directive I have following code:

```
$document.on("keydown", function(event)
{
    HandleKeys(event);
});

scope.$on("$destroy", function ()
{
    $document.off("keydown", HandleKeys);
});
```

`$document.on` works as expected and the `keydown`-event is registered. The `scope.$on`-event is called as well (once the scope is destroyed of course), how ever the `$document.off("keydown", HandleKeys);`-line doesn't work. "Doesn't work" means that the keydown event is still registered.

If I remove the `HandleKeys`-parameter to have have following line, it does work:

```
$document.off("keydown");
```

This is not what I want, as I want to specifically unbind the `HandleKeys`-function. Does anybody have an idea, why this doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are registering anonymous handler and de-registering `HandleKeys`. It wont de-register the original handler (anonymous function) that you had registered for `keydown`. You need to provide the same function reference to unregister as well, so using anonymous function does not help.

So Change:-

```
$document.on("keydown", function(event){
    HandleKeys(event);
});
```

to

```
$document.on("keydown", HandleKeys);
```

And it works when you do `$document.off("keydown")` is because it de-registers all the handlers attached to the document for keydown event, which is a bad thing to do anyways because you will end up de-regsitering any other keydown handlers attached by some other component.

Comment: Jep, I know, just found out my self, 1min after posting the question. Thanks for you reply!